# Shortcut to comment selected text when coding in OCaml in VSCode

Tags: ocaml, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a keyboard shortcut to surround selected text with (**)?

example `text selected_text other_text` to `text (*selected_text*) other_text`.

I know that selecting some text and clicking on "(" with surround it parentheses, is there a way to make vscode do the same thing with "*", so that selecting some text and clicking on "(" then "*" surrounds the text with "(*" and "*)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [toggle block comment (bound by default to `Ctrl-Shift-A`)](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) works. Just select a piece of code and hit `Ctrl-Shift-A` and it will be surrounded with `(*...*)`. Repeat to uncomment it.